# Using HTML/Javascript display the value of a radio button in a form textbox

Tags: javascript, html

How can I display the value of a radio button in a form text box? I'd like it to change when the radio button is clicked.

Here is my radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="testPassed" id="TestPassed" value="TestPassed">
<input type="radio" name="testFailed" id="TestFailed" value="TestFailed">
```

The text box:

```
<textarea name="description" cols="50" rows="5" id="description">Test Status: radioButtonValueHere </textarea>
```

Many thanks

Comment: The formatting of the question looks confusing.

Comment: Set name property the same, so that <input> controls can be radio buttons: name="testResults".

Comment: I think what @artdanil was trying to say is that you should use the `name` attribute to group your radio buttons appropriately. Read the following tutorial for more information: http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms10.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can implement an `OnClick` function with your radio button like this: `<input type="radio" name="sports" value="Football" onClick="doSomething();">` or you can have a function to iterate through all the radio buttons on your form and whichever is checked, will fill the textbox with your value:

```
<form name="myform">

<input type="text" id="txt" />

...

<script type="text/javascript">

for (i=0; i<document.myform.sports.length; i++) 

   if (document.myform.sports[i].checked==true)
   {
           t =t +document.myform.sports[i].value
   }
}

document.getElementById("txt").value=t
```

Comment: If you use the OnClick technique, be aware this won't fire if the radio button is selected in a way other than clicking. e.g. if user uses the keyboard or it's set programmatically.

Comment: @Rory: It depends on the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function that will pass the result value to the text area:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function writeResult(text){
    document.myform.testResultDescription.value = text;
}
//-->
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="myform">
    <input type="radio" name="testResults" id="TestPassed" value="TestPassed" onclick="writeResult('Test Passed');" />
    Test Passed<br />
    <input type="radio" name="testResults" id="TestFailed" value="TestFailed" onclick="writeResult('Test Failed');" />
    Test Failed<br />
    <textarea name="testResultDescription" cols="50" rows="5" id="testResultDescription"></textarea>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery this is really simple

HTML

```
<div id="radiobuttons">
<--! put here radios buttons -->
</div>

$("#radiobuttons input:radio").click(function() {
    $("textbox_id").val($(this).val());
});
```